# How to report number of Groovy tests to SonarQube

Tags: maven, unit-testing, groovy, sonarqube, spock

We've been adding an increasing number of Groovy (Spock) unit tests to our existing suite of Java (JUnit) tests.

We've configured things correctly to get Spock code coverage listed in Sonar, but the "Unit Test Success" listings - Tests, Failures, Errors, Skipped tests - only shows for the Java tests.

What configuration do we need to add for the Spock tests to report correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Those results in Java are fed by the Unit Test execution report, which is separate from the coverage report. [The docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project) tell you how to feed that data into an analysis.